# CMD: How to find numeric value of total memory in Windows in one line?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

In Linux we can:

```
grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'
```

What are the alternatives in Windows command prompt and PowerShell? I will run this command from ruby.

I have tried using:

```
wmic memorychip get /VALUE | findstr "Capacity"
```

to get the prefixed output of available bytes. But I need to get only numeric value out of it. And I could not find anything like sed in Windows.

Comment: Have you made any effort to find out yourself? Is there anything in particular you're stuck with?

Comment: An easy google nets a WMI query `(Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | measure-object Capacity -sum).sum/1gb`

Comment: @arco444, yes, I have the `wmic memorychip get /VALUE | findstr "Capacity"` command giving me prefixed output of available bytes. But I need to get only numeric value out of it. And I could not find anything like `sed` in windows, so I could complete this one-liner.

Comment: @arco444 but I also assume that command will fail on localized Windows environments.

Comment: I cannot tell if you are addressing me in this. I don't know what you mean by _localized_. Have you tried it? It returns a number (a string representation of a number). My solution is PowerShell based since you tagged it.

Comment: @Matt, no, I was referring to `wimc` command that I have been able to find myself. Your powershell solution works.

Comment: Pure CLI solution `wmic memorychip get Capacity|find /I /V "y"`. Use `find` or `findstr` command, in this case the output should be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple PowerShell answer this simple approach is brought to you by "Deranged PowerShell Zealot" from [BrianDesmond.com](http://www.briandesmond.com/windows-server/getting-total-installed-memory-with-wmi/). Look at the comments and not the blog post.

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | measure-object Capacity -sum).sum/1gb
```

That will return the GB value of memory installed on the computer. You can substitute `1gb` for `1mb` depending on your output needs.

If you are looking for a batch type solution consider adding that tag but understand that those solutions will most likely require for loops to parse the string tokens (I dont know for sure) so getting a one liner might not be as clean as you expect.